# Power query & power pivot - empty table and clearing pivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot, powerquery

Hope you could help.
I have the below code in my power query and it is working great with a connected power pivot table. 
As soon as the Source line is returning "This table is empty" it all goes wrong:

1. Power query return error message that the 2 lines following the source line, are not recognized.
2. The table in the power pivot is showing the last results from the last working query.

I need the table to be empty if there are no results.

How do i do that?

```
let

    UrlSource = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table6"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(UrlSource,{{"Url", type text}}),
    Url = #"Changed Type"{0}[Url],

    UserInput = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Sagsnummer Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(UserInput,{{"Sagsnummer", type text}}),
    Sagsnummer = #"Changed Sagsnummer Type"{0}[Sagsnummer],

    Source = OData.Feed(Url & "/FileContacts?$select=CustomLabel_Summary,Name/Name1&$expand=Name&$filter=File/FileNo eq '" & Sagsnummer & "'"),
    #"Expanded Name" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(Source, "Name", {"Name1"}, {"Name.Name1"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Name",{{"CustomLabel_Summary", "Rolle"}, {"Name.Name1", "Kontakt"}})

in

    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Answer (score 2):

Add one last step that check that both UrlSource and UserInput have a row of input. If not, default to some empty table:

```
= if Table.RowCount(UrlSource) > 0 and Table.RowCount(UserInput) > 0 then #"Renamed Columns" else #table({"Rolle", "Kontakt"}, {})
```

---

All together, your code would look like

```
let

    UrlSource = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table6"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(UrlSource,{{"Url", type text}}),
    Url = #"Changed Type"{0}[Url],

    UserInput = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Sagsnummer Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(UserInput,{{"Sagsnummer", type text}}),
    Sagsnummer = #"Changed Sagsnummer Type"{0}[Sagsnummer],

    Source = OData.Feed(Url & "/FileContacts?$select=CustomLabel_Summary,Name/Name1&$expand=Name&$filter=File/FileNo eq '" & Sagsnummer & "'"),
    #"Expanded Name" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(Source, "Name", {"Name1"}, {"Name.Name1"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Name",{{"CustomLabel_Summary", "Rolle"}, {"Name.Name1", "Kontakt"}}),

    Custom1 = if Table.RowCount(UrlSource) > 0 and Table.RowCount(UserInput) > 0 then #"Renamed Columns" else #table({"Rolle", "Kontakt"}, {})
in

    Custom1
```

Comment: Carl Tnx for the answer. i don't quite follow.. could you put it in my code? tnx

Comment: Sure thing. There's a button to add custom formula by the formula bar, it's good for adding one step to the bottom :)

Comment: Tnx Carl...appriciate it :-)